# How I can get the cos2 from the PCA results?

Tags: scikit-learn, pca, factominer

I would like to calculate the cos2 of variables and individuals in Sklearn, like the FactoMineR package does in R. Is there an alternative in pyhton?

In R with FactoMineR I do something like this

```r
pca_exp = PCA(df)
pca_exp[["ind"]][["cos2"]]
```

I got, something similar to this:

| Dim.1 | Dim.2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.81792535 | 0.1820747 |
| 0.81792535 | 0.1179768 |

In scikit-learn I'm doing this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Y1'] = [9,7,8,3,1,3,4,7,2,6]
df['Y2'] = [9,13,6,1,5,11,4,3,8,10]

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(2)
results_pca = pca.fit_transform(df)
```

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm looking for it too.

Comment: no, I had to perform the analysis in R